# writing data into cassandra at ceratin interval

Tags: apache-spark, timer, cassandra, parallel-processing

I am doing some kind of processing in spark and want to implement a functionality that regardless of the processing which is running I want to schedule a timer(at an interval of 5 minutes) which will persist some data into Cassandra( or let`s say any other source)

To make it more easy to understand ,it can sound like two task running in parallel,one is keeping track of 5 min interval which will write into Cassandra and other is doing all the processing which I have told it to do.

Its like I am doing processing on the streaming data and then I have cached the output of that processing in spark as temp table and this cached table is used somewhere again in spark script but only after some interval I want to persist in Cassandra.

Any sort of help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There are two APIs you can use:

1- Spark Streaming and use mapWithState function: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

In this case, you can set a 5min timeout for mapWithState and write the output to 
 Cassandra.

2- Spark Structured Streaming and mapGroupsWithState/flatMapGroupsWithState function: 
It gives you better flexibility to set the timeout (you can use both event time or processing time). Drawback is the API is very new and support for Cassandra is limited.

Comment: thanks for your answer sir,I am not able to understand it clearly(spark newbie).can you please provide an example?